# Container child flutter

Tags: flutter, app

Hola alguien ve o me puede explicar como poner dos hijos en el mismo container? si lo pruebo por separado los dos funcionan, me explico si pongo la imagen como titulo sale la imagen, si comento y pongo la clase Historias() sale... Pero quiero poner las dos cosas...
GRACIAS, por favor si alguien me ayuda!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Container(
              child:Image.network('url'),
              child: Historias(),
              ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          toolbarHeight: 85,
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Api()));
  }
}
```

---

vale muchas gracias! utilizaba container porque tiene scroll infinito y column no. Pero si estoy empezando con flutter y me queda aun mucha documentación, pero muchas gracias! ;)

Comment: Puedes marcar la pregunta como solucionada si te sirvió la respuesta que puse abajo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes dos opciones,

```
Container(
child: Column(
    children: [
        Image.network('url'),
        Historias(),
    ]
    )
)
```

o si quieres con Scroll

```
Container(
child: ListView(
    children: [
        Image.network('url'),
        Historias(),
    ]
    )
)
```

Puedes revisar la documentación y veras que los widgets que pueden tener múltiples Widgets tienen el parámetro ***children***

Saludos :)

Answer (score -1):

Antes de empezar a programar en alguna plataforma necesitas leer, sobretodo la documentación oficial donde trae toda la info que necesitas.

En el caso que mencionas es porque el `Container` solo recibe un `child`, si quieres agregar más elementos dentro de un Widget, puedes usar otros como `Column` o `Row` entre otros.

`Column` te permite agregas elementos en vertical, mientras que `Row` lo hace en horizontal.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Image.network('url'),
    Historias(),
  ]
 )
```

Te dejo el link para que sigas aprendiendo:  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout